# Error rendering with GLSL framebuffer

Tags: opengl, glsl, render, framebuffer

I am trying to get into screen a video frame in a 2d texture covering the screen, I must use framebuffers, because eventually I wish to do the ping-pong rendering technique. But for the time being I want first to achieve just to render on the screen by using framebuffers.

This is my setup code:

```
 // Texture setup

 int[] text = new int[1];
 glGenTextures(1, text, 0);
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, text[0]);
 glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
 glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, 512, 512, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

 // Frambuffer setup

 int[] fbo = new int[1];
 glGenFramebuffers(1, fbo, 0);
 glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo[0]);
 glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, text[0], 0);
 glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Till here all ok, I didn't write here the testing code to keep it small, but right after I check if the frame buffer was created correctly, and all is fine.

Now in my Render loop I do next:

```
 // Use the GLSL program

 glUseProgram(programHandle);

 // Swap to my FBO

 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
 glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo[0]);
 glViewport(0, 0, 512, 512);

 // Pass the new image data to the program so the fragment shader processes it.
 // Using glTexSubImage2D to speed up

 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, text[0]);
 glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_texture"), 0);
 glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 512, 512, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NewImageData);

 // Draw the quad

 glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

 // Swap back to the default screen frambuffer

 glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

At this point I get a black screen, and on the log I can see a GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION  1286.
I tried putting the glDrawArrays after the glBindFramebuffer call, but then the application crashes.
Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: int text[] = new int[1];???  int fbo = new int[1]; ???  No offence, but perhaps learning how to declare variables and arrays in C++ would be the first step before working out how to render a scene to a texture :p.

Comment: Oops, my fault, is just a typo while cleaning it up to paste it here. On the other hand is written in Java. I just have updated the code avobe as it should. I hope someone can see what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Ah.  It's Java.  Can you call int status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER); and see what it returns (after binding the buffer for use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LUMINANCE textures are not renderable, this means you can't render to them using a FBO. This problem is solved with the GL_ARB_texture_rg extension, which introduces one and two channel texture formats that are renderable.

Comment: The code must be run in Android, so I cannot use an extension that might not be common to all phone models. so I guess I have to rethink the whole approach.